# Can we port content from same publication level?

Tags: 2011, content-porter-2009

We have 03 main publication and then 04a,04b,04c,04d translated publication.

Our requirement is to copy all translated content from 04a and copy into 04e at same level.

Can we do this through Content Porter? What do I need to change in mapping.xml to do this?

I have a idea to change the webdev path of intermediate package to point 04e and import it.